# remove/hide past time in jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am using jqueryui datetimepicker and I have set minTime to 0 and minDate to 0 and stepMin to 5. But I am not able to hide the past time in the minute dropdown.

For example, 15 is current minute of the system so 00, 05 and 10 should not bedisplayed in the minute dropdown.

Below is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({  
      showSecond: false,
      dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
      timeFormat: "   HH:mm",
      controlType: 'select',
      oneLine: true,
      stepMinute: 5,
      minTime:0,
      minDateTime:0,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

      }
    });
});
```

Any one can help me out this?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI does not have a datetimepicker widget by default. are you using a jQuery plugin? if so, which one? the documentation might be helpful as there maybe a minTime option or something like that that can help you. Otherwise, you'll have to write a function that will remove all options that are before the current time.